# How can i override the margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0; css styles

Tags: html, css, css-float

I was creating a table, but my issue is that table border is not working because it calls some other css.

Here is my [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/2DQ6U/)

`margin: 0;
padding: 0;
border: 0;`

So how can i override the `margin: 0;padding: 0; border: 0;` , so that i can get the table border easily.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Just add a specific border setting to your table elements using a higher specificity selector. Check this [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) link for details about specificity.

Comment: You set them to some other value.

Comment: Sorry I actually thought there was a problem in this question, and extremely sorry I suggested `!important`. `!important` is apparently the 8th deadly sin.

Answer (score 3):

It's not about the margin nor padding, it's the `border: 0` that hides the border.

Add a rule for the table tds such as:

```
td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

to show `td` borders. The same applies to `table` tag. You would also probably want to take a look at the `border-collapse` property for `table` tag (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-collapse).

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/2DQ6U/10/

Furthermore, I suggest you to avoid any inline style definition if not strictly necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Remove `border:0` from CSS.

Take a look here:

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2DQ6U/2/)**

Comment: Thanks for ur help frnd, But without removing the border, i want only overriding technique.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I guess because he asked how to override the setting, not how to edit it

Comment: I didn't downvote either, but his `border:0` setting is from the CSS reset which is used to nullify any browser specific padding/border settings. Changing that would affect all other areas.

Answer (score 1):

It is better you can use class for the table and apply it through CSS.

**HTML**

```
<table class="testclass">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <span style="color:#000000;"><span style="font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif;"><strong>ID Number</strong></span></span></td>
                <td>
                    <span style="color:#000000;"><span style="font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif;"><strong>Room Name</strong></span></span></td>
                <td>
                    <span style="color:#000000;"><span style="font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif;"><strong>Name of Company</strong></span></span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <span style="color:#000000;"><strong><span style="font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif;">1</span></strong></span></td>
                <td>
                    <span style="color:#000000;"><span style="font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif;">Premier</span></span></td>
                <td>
                    Amsh Ltd</td>
            </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
table.testclass
{
border-top:1px solid #000;
border-left:1px solid #000;
border-collapse:collapse;
width:800px;
}
table.testclass td
{
border-right:1px solid #000;
border-bottom:1px solid #000;
padding:5px;
}
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/2DQ6U/9/)

Answer (score 1):

the reason your border doesnt work is because you are using "border-collapse: collapse" on the tbody. You need to instead use it on table styling.

here is the CSS you need to use

```
table,td{
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 1px;
}
```

Here is the HTML change. Notice the "border-collapse:collapse" in the table but not tbody which was your problem.

```
<table border="10" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="10" style="width: 800px;border-collapse: collapse;">
    
            <tbody style="border: 1px solid black; ">
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2DQ6U/11/)

Hope that helps.

Comment: great let me know if that's what you wanted.